# Angular SSR - abp is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, aspnetboilerplate, server-side-rendering

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate with Angular (6). I want to enable Server Side Rendering, primarily to enable sharing on social media. The build for server app goes well, I can serve the app, but when I open it on the configured port (localhost:42000), I get "Reference error: abp is not defined."

Before that, I got errors like "window is not defined" and "location is not defined" and I got rid of those by mocking the window, document, navigator and location objects in **server.ts** file.

I am not an Angular expert, so any help would be appreciated.

The first occurence of this problem is in `appInitializerFactory` function in **root.module.ts**.
Here is my **root.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, Injector, APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import { AbpModule } from '@abp/abp.module';
import { AbpHttpInterceptor } from '@abp/abpHttpInterceptor';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
import { ServiceProxyModule } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxy.module';
import { RootRoutingModule } from './root-routing.module';

import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { AppSessionService } from '@shared/session/app-session.service';
import { API_BASE_URL } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';

import { RootComponent } from './root.component';
import { AppPreBootstrap } from './AppPreBootstrap';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

export function appInitializerFactory(injector: Injector) {
  return () => {

    abp.ui.setBusy();
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
      AppPreBootstrap.run(() => {
        abp.event.trigger('abp.dynamicScriptsInitialized');
        var appSessionService: AppSessionService = injector.get(AppSessionService);
        appSessionService.init().then(
          (result) => {
            abp.ui.clearBusy();
            resolve(result);
          },
          (err) => {
            abp.ui.clearBusy();
            reject(err);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }
}

export function getRemoteServiceBaseUrl(): string {
  return AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl;
}

export function getCurrentLanguage(): string {
    return abp.localization.currentLanguage.name;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    AbpModule,
    ServiceProxyModule,
    RootRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    RootComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AbpHttpInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: API_BASE_URL, useFactory: getRemoteServiceBaseUrl },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
      deps: [Injector],
      multi: true
    },
      {
          provide: LOCALE_ID,
          useFactory: getCurrentLanguage
      }
  ],
  bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class RootModule {

}
```

Comment: You'd probably need to import `abp` from their script according to: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization

Comment: I think you need to create custom pages to be able to render server-side. because current implementation requires a lot of browser functions..

Comment: @Brandon - thanks, but this link only for Localization in MVC project. How would you import it in Angular project?

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu What kind of custom pages and how to perform that? Thank you.

Comment: @boriskisic you may have to add the script to your Angular app's index.html and define a global for it if they don't make the module available via npm or Github

Comment: check out https://medium.com/volosoft/building-a-simple-angular-universal-application-with-asp-net-boilerplate-hero-shop-c63f9a5249ae